# Smallest number containing the first 11 primes as sub-strings

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, primes

113257 contains the first 6 primes as sub-strings when reading them from left to right:

2: 113**2**57

3: 11**3**257

5: 1132**5**7

7: 11325**7**

11: **11**3257

13: 1**13**257

What is the smallest number that contains the first 11 primes as sub-strings?

Good luck!

Comment: Oh no a negative vote? Please tell me why so I can improve my questions.

Comment: Should the [tag:no-computers] tag be added?

Comment: Perhaps we could come up with a name for the sequence of numbers, where the nth number is the smallest number containing the first n primes as substrings. 

I wonder if this sequence has any interesting properties or methods of going from the nth to the n+1th element

Comment: I think that [this is cheating](https://oeis.org/A054261). @Cruncher

Comment: @XanderHenderson Heh, of course the sequence already exists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given the first 11 primes:

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31

We can observe that:

- We'll always get **2**, **3** and **7** for "free" (via other numbers, such as **23** and **17**, etc), so they can be ignored leaving only **5** to be explicitly included
- Of the double digit numbers it is possible to get either **13** and **31** for free (using 1**1** + **3**1 or [1/2]**3** + **1**[1/7/9]), but not both
- After doing the above, we can overlap one more teen at the end of some of the configurations (1131[7/9] or [1/2]311[7/9])
- The remaining five double digit numbers have to just be included as is, with no overlap

Therefore, our final number needs to be 5x2 (remaining double digits) + 1 (overlapped teen) + 1 (remaining 5) = 12 digits long.

Arranging things from smallest to largest, I believe that the smallest number containing the first 11 primes is:

> **113,171,923,295**

Or for completeness:

> **2**: 113,171,9**2**3,295
>  **3**: 11**3**,171,923,295
>  **5**: 113,171,923,29**5**
>  **7**: 113,1**7**1,923,295
>  **11**: **11**3,171,923,295
>  **13**: 1**13**,171,923,295
>  **17**: 113,**17**1,923,295
>  **19**: 113,17**1**,**9**23,295
>  **23**: 113,171,9**23**,295
>  **29**: 113,171,923,**29**5
>  **31**: 11**3**,**1**71,923,295

Comment: Nice!! Think you got me!

Comment: Now I want to ask what's the smallest *prime* containing the first 11 primes as substrings. But maybe there's no easy way to solve that :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Interesting question... I have discovered a truly remarkable proof that the number is bigger than the one above, but this margin is too small to contain it. ;)

Comment: You've forgotten the "7" in the completeness list. Nice solution, though.

Comment: @Gloweye - 7 never did deserve prime status. Overrated digit if you ask me. ;) (Thanks, fixed)

Comment: @Randal'Thor 11317192329511 is prime, but don't know if you can get smaller one.

Comment: @PaulEvans 113,175,192,329 is prime and still only 12 digits, so definitely smaller.  Might be possible to go even smaller though.

Comment: Soddit. [There ya go](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/89448/5373), @DarrelHoffman, PaulEvans, and Alconja. Hope it's still a decent puzzle :-)

Answer (score 2):

> 113171923295 (12 digits)
>
>  .......2_
>  ..3_
>  ...........5
>  ....7_
>  11_
>  .13_
>  ...17_
>  .....19_
>  .......23_
>  .........29_
>  ..31_

Answer (score 0):

Primes are

> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31. We can combine 2, 3, and 23; 17 and 7. If we stick 23 and 19 next to each other we can get 31. To minimize, we will use the smallest first digits, as much as possible: 11, then 13. We will then need a 19 and 29 at the end, followed by the final 5. There are a maximum of 18 digits in the number; since the 2, 3, and 7 are combined this is 15 digits. The second 1 in the 11 and the 31 can be shared with the first 1 in either 13, 17, 19, so this reduces by 2 digits. The first digit in the 31 can be shared by the last 3 in the 13 or 23, so this reduces by another digit. I think this means that the minimum number of digits to accomplish everything is 12, so hopefully my number below works.

So potentially we could have

> 113172319295, which yields 
>  113172319**2**95 
>  113172**3**19295 
>  11317231929**5** 
>  1131**7**2319295 
>  **11**3172319295 
>  1**13**172319295 
>  113**17**2319295 
>  1131723**19**295 
>  11317**23**19295 
>  113172319**29**5 
>  113172**31**9295

Answer (score 0):

A nice algorithm to generate the series

The first 11 prime numbers are

> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31

Sorting them lexicographically we get

> 11, 13, 17, 19, 2, 23, 29, 3, 31, 5, 7

or as a single number

> 111317192232933157

**Step-1**
Remove all repetitive numbers (not digits) (highlighted in **bold**)

**1**1131719**2**2329**3**3157

> 113171923293157

**Step-2**
Traversing from left to right, remove any numbers from the first 11 primes already seen

```
  ┌─────────┐         
  ↓         ↓
11317192329 31 5 7
    ↑            ↑
    └────────────┘
```

**Step-3**. Verify.

> **2**: 1131719**2**3295
>  **3**: 11**3**171923295
>  **5**: 11317192329**5**
>  **7**: 1131**7**1923295 
>  **11**: **11**3171923295
>  **13**: 1**13**171923295 
>  **17**: 113**17**1923295
>  **19**: 11317**19**23295
>  **23**: 1131719**23**295
>  **29**: 113171923**29**5
>  **31**: 11317192**32**95

**Answer**

> 113171923295

Comment: While this is a very attractive approach, I don't see why it must generate the smallest example in general. Perhaps starting with a different order yields more numbers that can be removed from fortunate coincidences.